# Chrome 83 doesn't connect WP login page after update from http to https on localhost

Tags: login, ssl, https, google-chrome

I enabled the flag "allow-insecure-localhost" on Chrome 83 to accept my localhost WP site to cure the ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR. But the Chrome warning page show again and cannot connect to the WP_login page.
https://localhost:8080/whweb/wp-admin/

[image: Chrome refuse to connect]

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening in an incognito tab then fix your ssl issue by installing a valid certificate.

Comment: Thank you, Falz for the reply. 
I am very new to all this, everything is created on my local PC. 
What I do have is:
– WP 5.4.2
– XAMPP v.3.2.4 installed on my Windows 10 (64bit) PC

I created a new SSL certificate using the plugin “really-simple-ssl.3.3.3” but I am not sure if it was placed in the correct WP folder, nor how to get Chrome to fetch it. I still get the above picture “Secure origins http://localhost:8080” and “Unknown / cancelled https://localhost:8080”. 
So, what I need to know is the details of “fix your ssl issue by installing a valid certificate.” Any help with this?

Comment: This does not look like a WordPress issue. You will need to research how to enable SSL on XAMP try: https://gist.github.com/nguyenanhtu/33aa7ffb6c36fdc110ea8624eeb51e69